# Accessing Parse MBaaS

Tags: android, ios, mobile, parse-platform, mbaas

I've been searching for good MBaaS provider. I found Parse is a completely open source project and it has enough features and is free to use. Also, I read that Parse has been acquired by Facebook. My questions are below:

1.) Can I develop my app to access Parse MBaaS service newly now or this service will be completely closed and FB is not going to re-open it in future?

2.) Where can I get developer documentation for Parse MBaaS

3.) Is there a related community or forum for Parse MBass?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Parse will be closed soon (January 2017 ) i think , better use your own backend or you can use [Backendless](https://backendless.com/)  ,its free and has the same fonctionality that parse provides .

Answer (score 0):

Parse is going to shutdown soon , but the good part is FB had made it open source that means you can deploy ur own instance of Parse, which i think is even more great .

Comment: I know FB acquired it and made it open source. My worry is, they are going to completely close from next year right? Does "Parse Server" is the one, who enables mBaas http://parse.com/ ? Where can i get documentation to enable mBaas services to my app?

Comment: Another thing I want to know Parse's mBaas features like it supports push notification etc. what are all features does supported by Parse mBaas?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy parse backend on your server .Please refer official doc for features .